# apache2: Syntax error on line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I installed apache2 in my ubutu server 20.04, but when i troubleshoot the syntax by `sudo apache2 -t`, it gives me the following errro:

```
[Sun Apr 17 08:43:12.116347 2022] [core:warn] [pid 34462] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined
apache2: Syntax error on line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot
```

but the apache2 is running and active status.

Answer (score 10):

Running the following command fixed my problem:

```
source /etc/apache2/envvars
```

Answer (score 1):

`apache2` is deprecated. Use `apachectl -t`.